# How to limit user from being able to read and copy the content of /opt/lampp/htdocs/* while he can start the PC and launch all the websites from it?

Tags: ubuntu, xampp

There is a PC which is running an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS OS. It is hosting websites using xampp (Apache + PHP + MySQL). All the setup has been made by a web developer who is a root user. So far, there is a need to distribute this PC to customers who suppose to only be able to benefit from the hosted websites services, but not being able to read, or copy its source code (PHP script). Only a root user should be able to do so. How can this be achieved? Please notice that I'm not a geek in Linux neither in English.

Comment: If you hand a physical computer system over to anybody for more than a couple of minutes (or seconds), you can assume that they have access to everything on the system and can change it at will. What you want can't be done.

Comment: What if the person cannot have access to the physical hard drive ? I guess you mean that he can remove the hard drive from the PC in order to take data from it via cable (USB)... otherwise I still don't realize how can be possible to fetch protected data from a Linux OS without having the right permission to do so.

Comment: Booting a live distribution gives root automatically - takes 2 minutes. Removing the disk and mounting it as a data disk elsewhere is fast. How do you give someone physical access to the system without giving them physical access to the disk?

Comment: Ok I get you so the solution would be to obfuscate the source codes or encrypt them I isn't it ?